# 13.10 Virtual Hosts file doesn't work

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I already know of the main .conf problem with Ubuntu 13.10 and the change to Apache 2.4 for the suffix to site-available files.

My problem is that when I enable "a2ensite xxxx" for "xxx.conf" in "sites-available" folder, I get this message when I restart/reload Apache:

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

Then I can "a2dissite xxxx" and get apache to run again. I don't know why this is. My .conf file is as follows:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin alex@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ethico/docroot
    ServerName ethico-r6.dev
    ServerAlias *.ethico-r6.dev www.ethico-r6.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Also for /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   *.ethico-r6.dev  www.ethico-r6.dev
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

-Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add the `Listen` directive in your virtual host configuration. It is already configured in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.

This is making apache listen to the port 80 more than once.

> #### Error condition
>
> Multiple Listen directives for the same ip address and port will result in an Address already in use error message.
>   <sup>Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen</sup>

---

On a side note, the `NameVirtualHost` has no effect in apache 2.4

> The NameVirtualHost directive no longer has any effect, other than to emit a warning. Any address/port combination appearing in multiple virtual hosts is implicitly treated as a name-based virtual host.
>   <sup>Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#misc</sup>

Comment: Thanks Dan. Taking out the Listen directive did fix the problem. On the side note however, I read this in another stackoverflow: "I think you are missing NameVirtualHost *:80 in your main config file. This will more or less disable name based virtual hosts (*:80)." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518907/virtual-host-on-ubuntu-13-10-and-apache-2-4-6   I also took  NameVirtualHost out, but you are saying that note is not right?

Comment: @AlexFinnarn I don't believe it's true. Maybe he is still using the old httpd.conf file of apache 2.2. But I can assure that I don't have the `NameVirtualHost` in my apache configs. And everything is working as expected.